# Troubleshooting TypeScript Error in React-Select Async Integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I would greatly appreciate assistance with an issue I've been encountering over the past few days.

I am currently utilizing a third-party library known as [react-select](https://react-select.com/home#async) to create a select dropdown that possesses the capability to send requests to an API when text is inputted.

Below is the code I'm working with:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

import categories from '@/data/categories';

import groupCategoriesByType from '../utils/groupCategoriesByType';
import getCategories from '../api/getCategories';

const selectStyles = {
  menu: (base) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 20 }),
};

const loadOptions = async (
  inputValue: string,
  callback: (
    options: {
      label: string;
      options: string | { value: string; label: string }[];
    }[]
  ) => void
) => {
  const response = await getCategories(inputValue);
  const groupedCategories = groupCategoriesByType(response);
  callback(groupedCategories);
};

function Category() {
  const groupedCategories = groupCategoriesByType(categories);
  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      defaultOptions={groupedCategories}
      loadOptions={loadOptions}
      styles={selectStyles}
    />
  );
}

export default Category;
```

The issue I'm encountering arises on the loadOptions={loadOptions} line, specifically, a TypeScript error with the following message:

```
Type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: { label: string; options: string | {    value: string;    label: string;}[]; }[]) => void) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(inputValue: string, callback: (options: OptionsOrGroups<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }, GroupBase<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }>>) => void) => void | Promise<...>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<OptionsOrGroups<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }, GroupBase<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }>>>'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<OptionsOrGroups<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }, GroupBase<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }>>>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'OptionsOrGroups<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }, GroupBase<{ label: string; options: string | { value: string; label: string; }[]; }>>'.ts(2322)
```

Additionally, here's my getCategories(...) function, responsible for making a backend call to retrieve data:

```
import api from '@/config/api';

async function getCategories(term: string) {
  try {
    const response = await api.post('/get_results', { searchTerm: term });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.data;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

export default getCategories;
```

And lastly, here's my `groupCategoriesByType(...)` function, which takes an array of objects in the form of `[{ value: string; label: string; type: string; }]` and groups them based on their type to produce output in the following form: `{ label: string; options: [{ value: string; label: string }] }`

```
import { CategoryType } from '@/types';

function groupCategoriesByType(categories: CategoryType[]) {
  // Create an object to store the grouped categories.
  const groupedCategories: {
    label: string;
    options: { value: string; label: string }[];
  } = {
    label: '',
    options: [],
  };

  // Group categories by the 'type' attribute.
  categories.forEach((category) => {
    const { type, ...rest } = category;

    if (!groupedCategories[type]) {
      groupedCategories[type] = [];
    }

    groupedCategories[type].push(rest);
  });

  // Convert the 'groupedCategories' object into the desired format.
  const result = Object.entries(groupedCategories).map(([label, options]) => ({
    label,
    options,
  }));

  // Return the 'result' array.
  return result;
}

export default groupCategoriesByType;
```

PS: I have a `CategoryType` as well:

```
export type CategoryType = {
  value: string;
  label: string;
  type: string;
};
```

Here's a demo linked to by react-select's documentation that I am following, you might find helpful:
https://codesandbox.io/s/qqy65g?module=/example.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the callback parameter in your loadOptions function because the function is expected to return a Promise that resolves to the options. The getCategories function already returns a Promise, so you can directly return the groupedCategories from within loadOptions. Try this and see if it works,

```js
const loadOptions = async (inputValue: string) => {
  const response = await getCategories(inputValue);
  const groupedCategories = groupCategoriesByType(response);
  return groupedCategories;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do the trick. Is it me or is the documentation a bit ambigous on this?

Comment: Great! Documentation is pretty clear, but not straight forward tbh. You have to connect the dots. In doc, if you select an item from promise option, then click on the code icon(</>), it clearly shows a resolved promise is being returned. In your code you have an await statement. So I figured, why not just return that instead of unnecessary complexity? I am glad that it worked tho.